# Blender Cycles - Hair Edges are Gray

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, hair

I've been trying to render hair in Cycles, but for some reason when I render them with transparency and what not the textures come out with grayish edges. It might be something to do with the alpha settings but I'm not entirely sure. For the sake of simplicity i omitted her other hair particles besides the ones shown. Is there a way to get rid of the white outlines?

[image: Naotora render]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with pre-multiplied alpha channels in the PNG image, though I am not sure how to solve it correctly in Blender.

I suspect the problem here is the alpha map transitions softly from hair color to transparent, but the Cycles transparency has a different color from the opaque area (in this case white).

One way to work around it that might mitigate the problem is to change the color of the transparent material to match the color of the hair.

Try plugging in the Image color output to the color input socket of the *Transparent* node also, to see if it helps.

Depending on how the hair color is setup (if the transparent areas of the image still have hair color) it may reduce the issue.

Comment: I tried plugging the image color output into the Transparent color socket, but that didn't quite work. But your response made me realize that the textures themselves weren't PNG files, but were dds files.

I exported the textures from Noesis as PNG files and everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: You should post that as a full answer bellow for future reference. Please include some details about what you did, why it didn't work before and how you solved it.